# Wix Outlook Add-In for all users on a terminal server

Tags: outlook, wix, windows-installer, add-in

I got from my software vendor a batch file which compile some components together based on an wxs file (wix ?) with candle and light to create an outlook add-in installer.

Unfortunately, the msi setup file created only install for the current user.

Since I want to use the result on a terminal server and it should only be installed once by the administration, I think that I have to adapt the wxs file to allow the setup file to install for all users on the terminal server, right ?

I cannot find any hints on google or such, on how to adapt it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have wxs file and any code in it?

Answer (score 0):

Change InstallScope of Package from perUser to perMachine as below

```
<Package InstallScope="perMachine" />
```

There will be other properties of course but this is the one important to you.

Also there can be other changes needed for changing installer from per user to per machine. For eg if there are registry keys you will probably need to change those from `HKCU` to `HKLM`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
However, I got this error:  
  
LGHT0204 : ICE57: Component 'ADXLOADER.DLL' has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine KeyPath.  
  
And this  
  
LGHT0204 : ICE38: Component RESET.CSS installs to user profile. It's KeyPath registry key must fall under HKCU.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860316/ice38-component-installs-to-user-profile-error-for-a-specific-component check this. something in the setup is still doing per user installations like your component RESET.CSS also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245832/wix-program-files-shortcut-for-per-machine-install